# Jekyll on Heroku with LetsEncrypt

Tags: ssl, heroku, jekyll, lets-encrypt

I have my site www.foo.bar hosted on Heroku successfully, but now I want to add ssl cert to my site using LetsEncrypt.  In order to successfully do this, I need to generate a directory www.foo.bar/.well-known/acme-challenge/{{insert random string here}} that displays a random code.

I followed [this](https://www.cheeyeo.uk/letsencrypt/ruby/jekyll/ssl/2016/02/07/setting_up_ssl_with_jekyll_and_lets_encrypt/) post. It did nothing for me.  I could not get the .well-known route to work.  I could only see "not found" when I navigated to that page.

In addition, I tried moving the /.well-known directory to the project root and added both:

```
include: ['.well-known/acme-challenge']
keep_files: ['.well-known/acme-challenge']
```

to my _config.yml file.

Anyone else have suggestions or successfully done this?